# Javascript turns my php visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is **test123.php**:

```
<?php
echo "<html>";
echo "<head>";
echo "</head>";
echo "<body>";
echo '<form class="show_playerlist" id="show_playerlist" onsubmit="return false">';
echo '<center><input type="submit" value="Submit"></center><br>';
echo "</form>";
echo '<span id="test" style="display:none">ok</span>';
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="jqueryui/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>';
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="test123.js">';
echo "</script>";
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
?>
```

This is the **test123.js**:

```
$(".show_playerlist").submit(function(){
     $("#test").show();
});
```

When I open the php in my browser and submit the form, I can see the php by using Firebug:
In Firebug between CSS and DOM there is script, which should be only showing my javascript. But it also shows the test123.php AFTER executing the javascript.
Without any javascript the php isn't shown in Firebug script, as it should be.

Comment: where is your php code ??

Comment: There is no PHP in your test123.php.

Comment: it's not needed, I also could echo all of it and still the same, ok I edit....

Comment: I know pretty much nothing about php but your snippet is using jQuery(javascript) to reveal `test`.  Without javascript you don't have any way to show it.

Comment: provide sample of what you are seeing in firebug....problem description doesn't make sense

Comment: If you think your PHP was exposed when you submit the form, then try removing the "display:none" that was set to$("#test"). Your php code might have been exposed already due to the code not executing on the server. OR you are calling it from the file protocol.

Comment: @JayBlanchard submit won't reload with code shown

Comment: Yep, I missed the inline return false @charlietfl

Comment: Thanks for your help, so you think it's displayed only because everything is revealed; so if I enter some php variable it shouldn't be shown. I try that.

Comment: You haven't shown us what you are actually seeing in firebug ... therefore issue is not clear at all. WHat does `see the php` mean?

Comment: OK thanks I answered it for me and gonna accept it in 2 days.... charlietfl well it's the php html echo I am shown.

Comment: `so you think it's displayed only because everything is revealed` - no, totally wrong, has nothing to do with your `show`, you could have an empty function

Comment: Ok ok, why does it show the html also in the script part as *.php? I don't see the reason :(

Comment: that's the name of the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not your PHP showing, that's the HTML ... firebug shows javascript, and if your html has javascript ONLY in an attribute (like onsubmit in your example), it wont get shown in firebug until it fires

When it is shown, it's shown in the context of the HTML (not PHP) that it is contained in - so, displays the source of your page, the HTML source that is

This also works this way in the firefox built in developer tools in the debugger tab

This will also show up in the debugger tab only once the submit button is pressed - save it as .html - PHP is irrelevant

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <form onsubmit='return false;' >
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```